# Fortran Matrix Multiplication isn't giving the right answers

Tags: math, matrix, fortran, fortran90

I've got a matrix calculator program, but I'm getting the wrong answer for my dot product multiplier.

Here's my multiply subroutine:

```
subroutine multiply(m1,m2,res,row1,row2,col1,col2)
    integer, intent(in) :: row1,row2,col1,col2
    real, intent(in), dimension(row1,col1) :: m1
    real, intent(in), dimension(row2,col2) :: m2
    real, intent(out), dimension(row1,col2) :: res

    integer :: i,j,k

    do i = 1, col2
        do j = 1, col1
            res(j, i) = 0
        enddo
        do j = 1, col1
            do k = 1, row1
                res(k, i) = res(k, i) + m1(k, j)*m2(j, i)
            enddo
        enddo
    enddo
```

And here's my output, just in case that's the problem.

```
        subroutine output(r,c,matrix,name)
            integer, intent(in) :: r
            integer, intent(in):: c
            character(len=10) :: name
            real, intent(out), dimension(3,3) :: matrix


            integer i,j

            print *,name
            do i = 1, r
                    write(*,"(100F6.1)") ( matrix(i,j), j=1,c )
            enddo
        end subroutine
```

If it helps, it works excellently for a 3x3 matrix, but not for two rectangular matrix.  Here's what happens when I do a 2x3 * 3x2 matrix.  At this point, i'm desperate for help.  Anything you could suggest would be great.  Thanks!

[image]

EDIT:  Here's all of my code in its current state with your suggestions.

```
        PROGRAM G6P5
        integer :: r1,r2,c1,c2,i,j,k,s
        real :: input
        real, dimension (3,3) :: mat1, mat2, rmat
        write (*,*) 'Please make a selection:'
        write (*,*) 'Enter 1 to add matrices'
        write (*,*) 'Enter 2 to subtract matrices'
        write (*,*) 'Enter 3 to multiply matrices'
        write (*,*) 'Enter 4 to transpose a matrix'
        write (*,*) 'Enter 5 to quit'
        read *, s
        select case (s)
            case (1)
                print *, 'Enter # of rows & columns (1-10) (ex. 3 3 = 3x3)'
                read *, r1,c1
              print *, 'Matrix 1:'
                call fillmatrix(r1,c1,mat1)
                r2 = r1
                c2 = c1
                print *, 'Matrix 2:'
                call fillmatrix(r2,c2,mat2)
                call output(r1,c1,mat1,'Matrix 1: ')
                call output(r2,c2,mat2,'Matrix 2: ')
                rmat = mat1+mat2
                call output(r1,c1,rmat,'Sum:      ')
            case (2)
                print *, 'Enter # of rows & columns (1-10) (ex. 3 3 = 3x3)'
                read *, r1,c1
              print *, 'Matrix 1:'
                call fillmatrix(r1,c1,mat1)
                r2 = r1
                c2 = c1
                print *, 'Matrix 2:'
                call fillmatrix(r2,c2,mat2)
                rmat = mat1-mat2
                call output(r1,c1,mat1,'Matrix 1: ')
                call output(r2,c2,mat2,'Matrix 2: ')
                call output(r1,c1,rmat,'Sum:      ')
            case (3)
                print *, 'Enter # of rows & columns for matrix 1'
                print *, '(1 through 10, ex: 3 3 = 3x3)'
                read *, r1,c1
              print *, 'Matrix 1:'
                call fillmatrix(r1,c1,mat1)
                print *, 'Enter # of rows & columns for matrix 2'
                print *, '(1 through 10, ex: 3 3 = 3x3)'
                read *, r2,c2
              print *, 'Matrix 2:'
                call fillmatrix(r2,c2,mat2)
                if (c1.eq.r2) then
                    call multiply(mat1,mat2,rmat,r1,r2,c1,c2)
                    call output(r1,c1,mat1,'Matrix 1: ')
                    call output(r2,c2,mat2,'Matrix 2: ')
                    call output(r1,c2,rmat,'Product:  ')
                end if
            case (4)
                print *, 'Enter # of rows & columns for matrix 1'
                print *, '(1 through 10, ex: 3 3 = 3x3)'
                read *, r1,c1
              print *, 'Matrix 1:'
                call fillmatrix(r1,c1,mat1)
                call transpose(mat1,rmat,r1,c1)
                call output(r1,c1,rmat,'Transpose:')
            case (5)
                print *,'5'
            case default
                print *,'default'
        end select
        !       call fillmatrix(rows,columns,mat1)
        !       write (*,*) matrix1
        END PROGRAM




        subroutine fillmatrix(r,c,matrix)
            integer, intent(in) :: r
            integer, intent(in):: c
            real, intent(out), dimension(3,3) :: matrix

            integer i,j

            do i=1,r
                do j = 1,c
                    write (*,'(A,I2,A,I2,A)') 'Enter value (',i,',',j,').'
                    read*, matrix(i,j)
                enddo
            enddo
        end subroutine


        subroutine multiply(m1,m2,res,row1,row2,col1,col2)
            integer, intent(in) :: row1,row2,col1,col2
            real, intent(in), dimension(row1,col1) :: m1
            real, intent(in), dimension(row2,col2) :: m2
            real, intent(out), dimension(row1,col2) :: res

            integer :: i,j,k

            res = 0
            do i = 1, row1
                 do j = 1, col2
                      do k = 1, col1   ! col1 must equal row2
                         res(i, j) = res(i, j) + m1(i, k)*m2(k, j)
                      enddo   ! k
                    enddo  ! j
            enddo  ! i


        end subroutine


        subroutine transpose(m1,res,row,col)
            integer, intent(in) :: row,col
            real, intent(in), dimension(row,col) :: m1
            real, intent(out), dimension(row,col) :: res

            integer :: i,j,k
            do i = 1,col
                do j = 1,row
                    res(i,j) = m1(j,i)
                enddo
            enddo
        end subroutine



        subroutine output(r,c,matrix,name)
            integer, intent(in) :: r
            integer, intent(in):: c
            character(len=10) :: name
            real, intent(in), dimension(r,c) :: matrix


            integer i,j

            print *,name
            do i = 1, r
                    write(*,"(100F6.1)") ( matrix(i,j), j=1,c )
            enddo
        end subroutine
```

Comment: Can you just copy and paste your output?  It makes it difficult to copy and paste those numbers into my editor to help you.  Also, what matrix output do you expect?

Comment: Oh, sure, sorry.  Well now my output is this
` Matrix 1: `
`   1.0   0.0   5.0`
`   4.0   2.0   0.0`
` Matrix 2: `
`   6.0   4.0`
`   3.0   2.0`
`   3.0   5.0`
` Product:  `
`  21.0  29.0`
`  30.0  20.0`


However, I entered 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 for the first matrix

Comment: Each time you pass your matrix to a subroutine, do this instead: `call sub(r1,c1,mat(1:r1,1:c1))`.  If that works, I'll explain why in my answer.

Comment: Also, I meant copy the output into the question itself so it is properly formatted.

Comment: Did the `mat(1:r1,1:c1)` trick work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get matrix multiplication (via dot product) to give the correct answer. Also issues transposing matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284828/cant-get-matrix-multiplication-via-dot-product-to-give-the-correct-answer-al)

Comment: Maybe you could look into [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) libraries - you do not need to re-invent the wheel! There is a very nice article on wikipedia on [matrix multiplies in BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Matrix_Multiply). This could save you a lot of time (and nerves)... Or, use Fortran intrinsics like[`matmul`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MATMUL.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the indexing a little confused.  Try this.

```
res = 0
do i = 1, col2
    do j = 1, row1
        do k = 1, col1
            res(j, i) = res(j, i) + m1(j, k)*m2(k, i)
        enddo
    enddo
enddo
```

---

I also notice that in your `output` routine you have the line

```
real, intent(out), dimension(3,3) :: matrix
```

If you are sending `matrix` into this routine, it should be `intent(in)`.  Also, if you are printing a 2x2 matrix, then the `dimension(3,3)` is also incorrect.  You should change this line to

```
real, intent(in) :: matrix(r,c)
```

---

One last thing you might consider.  Your matrix is always 3x3, but you are not always using all the elements.  That is why you pass the number of rows and columns to the subroutines.  The issue here is that the actual size of the matrix needs to match these numbers.  To do this, you need to use the slice notation.

Instead of

```
call sub(2,2,mat)
```

use

```
call sub(2,2,mat(1:2,1:2))
```

This is because the first method is essentially equivalent to

```
call sub(2,2,mat(1:3,1:3))
```

Which will result in a mismatch between what you are passing to the subroutine and what the subroutine expects.  This can cause funny things to happen, as you saw.

Comment: Hmmm, very well could be.  I tried this but I'm still getting the same output

Comment: Hmmm, well that's definitely a start.  Apparently my first comment didn't save, but when I changed to your multiplication algorithm, it had the same output.  As for the other comments, now I get http://imgur.com/OzK6Y48  this.